# Javascript caching in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm tryin' to integrate the live chat system (like Livezilla) into my Rails 4 website. I've got the following code which I need to place on every page just before the closing `<body>` tag.

```
<!-- NETROXSC CODE. Theme No. 1 --><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.netroxsc.ru/E9DDC181-6448-D1DE-6451-AC0D48A9FB24/c.js?tmpl=1"></script>
```

So, I place it in my **application.html.erb**, but it executes only once - when the website loads or when I refresh any page.

How can I prevent Rails from caching that script? I've already installed the **jquery.turbolinks** gem for another purposes, but in this case it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: could you provide little more info on how you use the script that you include? Is there some kind of init function or DOM binding you need to call when you'r page reloads? or do you just have to include the javascript file and it does it's thing ?

Comment: This script initializes live chat window. As I suppose, it is generated dynamically on the side of the provider of that service. So, unfortunately, I don't think I can write some JQuery function and include it to application.js or another js file which will be compiled by asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can include your JS file if it is placed in this location:

```
app/assets/javascripts/home.js
```

Include this line in your application.js file

```
//= require home
```

Comment: This script is provided by live chat service. I suppose that it is generated dynamically on their side and includes different parameters of the chat window that I can change via web-interface on their website. So the trick is to make Rails execute exactly that link to script on each page.

By the way - I've tried to include that script on several templates separately, and it's not working even that way.